# CTRL+C doesn't interrupt call to shared-library using CTYPES in Python

Tags: python, c, signals, shared-libraries, ctypes

When calling a loop being performed in a C shared-library (dynamic library), Python will not receive a KeyboardInterrupt, and nothing will respond (or handle) CTRL+C.

What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you use `PyDLL` or `PYFUNCTYPE`; the GIL is released during the ctypes calls. Therefore the Python interpreter should handle SIGINT by raising `KeyboardInterrupt` in the main thread if the C code doesn't install its own signal handler.

To allow the Python code to run in the main thread; you could put the ctypes call into a background thread:

```
import threading

t = threading.Thread(target=ctypes_call, args=[arg1, arg2, ...])
t.daemon = True
t.start()
while t.is_alive(): # wait for the thread to exit
    t.join(.1)
```

Comment: The GIL! Of course. Thanks, JF. That's worth giving you the answer instead of taking it for myself.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to declare a signal handler for SIGINT, within the C, which is, hopefully, your project.

Comment: My experience with SIGINT in shared objects is that a handler is needed. It is not enough to block signals and have a thread waiting using sigwait.

Answer (score 1):

I used a threaded solution but then switched to a signal one. 
The work-around I use is to send SIGTERM from SIGINT handler, e.g.:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda s, f : os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM))
```

Here I just want to save a core idea of the solution to find it faster next time and the reason why I have changed the approach. The threaded variant does not suite for me because OpenMP becomes significantly slower when it is called not from the main thread.