# Allowing Ctrl-C to interrupt a python C-extension

Tags: python, linux, python-c-api

I'm running some computationally heavy simulation in (home-made) C-based python extensions. Occasionally I get stuff wrong and would like to terminate a simulation. However, Ctrl-C doesn't seem to have any effect (other than printing `^C` to the screen) so I have to kill the process using `kill` or the system monitor.

As far as I can see python just waits for the C extension to finish and doesn't really communicate with it during this time.

Is there a way to make this work?

*Update*: The main answers (for my specific problem) turned out to be:
 1. rewrite the code to regularly pass control back to the caller (answer [Allowing Ctrl-C to interrupt a python C-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707049/allowing-ctrl-c-to-interrupt-a-python-c-extension/14707300#14707300) below), or
 2. Use `PyErr_CheckSignals()` (answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33652496/423420 below)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python

Comment: related: [CTRL+C doesn't interrupt call to shared-library using CTYPES in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14271697/4279)

Comment: Read [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) it is extremely relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would redesign the C extensions so that they don't run for a long period.

So, split them into more elementary steps (each running for a short period of time, e.g. 10 to 50 milliseconds), and have these more elementary steps called by Python code.

[continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) might be relevant to understand, as a programming style...

Comment: Sorry, not an option at all in this case :)
It's a simulation with a huge number of steps & speed is essential. Interfacing with python at each step (or even at regular intervals) would ruin the efficiency.

Comment: Try to bunch the steps into something lasting a few milliseconds. Then the overhead of going to Python is negligible...

Comment: It's certainly worth thinking about, but it does raise a lot of issues with memory management etc. Thanks!

Comment: Haven't implemented it yet, but this is definitely on my todo list. Thanks again!

Answer (score 21):

> However, Ctrl-C doesn't seem to have any effect

[`Ctrl-C` in the shell sends `SIGINT` to the foreground process group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149741/1321). `python` on receiving the signal sets a flag in C code. If your C extension runs in the main thread then no Python signal handler will be run (and therefore you won't see `KeyboardInterrupt` exception on `Ctrl-C`) unless you call [`PyErr_CheckSignals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_CheckSignals) that checks the flag (it means: it shouldn't slow you down) and runs Python signal handlers if necessary or if your simulation allows Python code to execute (e.g., if the simulation uses Python callbacks). Here's a [code example of an extension module for CPython created using pybind11 suggested by @Matt](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-properly-handle-ctrl-c-in-long-running-functions):

```cpp
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m)
{
    m.def("long running_func", []()
    {
        for (;;) {
            if (PyErr_CheckSignals() != 0)
                throw py::error_already_set();
            // Long running iteration
        }
    });
}
```

If the extension runs in a background  thread then it is enough to release GIL (to allow Python code to run in the main thread that enables the signal handlers to run). `PyErr_CheckSignals()`  always returns `0` in a background thread.

Related: [Cython, Python and KeybordInterrupt ingored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16769870/4279)

Comment: Is there a pure-python way to detect SIGINT in a callback, main.py -> long-running scipy optimizer which calls a shared lib -> callback.py ? (Shall I ask a new question ?)

Comment: @denis: " pure-python way to detect SIGINT" -> KeyboardInterrupt is raised in the main thread (with the default signal handler).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There are legit reasons you may have to wait on a condition variable or something if you are doing blocking I/O that are unavoidable. You cannot always rearchitect around it.

Comment: I found this helpful: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-properly-handle-ctrl-c-in-long-running-functions

Answer (score 8):

Python has a signal handler installed on `SIGINT` which simply sets a flag that is checked by the main interpreter loop. For this handler to work properly, the Python interpreter has to be running Python code.

You have a couple of options available to you:

1. Use `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS`/`Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` to release the GIL around your C extension code. You cannot use any Python functions when not holding the GIL, but Python code (and other C code) may run concurrently with your C thread (true multithreading). A separate Python thread can execute alongside the C extension and catch Ctrl+C signals.
2. Set up your own `SIGINT` handler and call the original (Python) signal handler. Your `SIGINT` handler can then do whatever it needs to do to cancel the C extension code and return control to the Python interpreter.

Comment: (1) [releasing GIL would make any difference only if the C extension runs in a background thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14271697/4279).  (2) [call `Py_Err_CheckSignals()` instead of manuall calling Python signal handler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33652496/4279)

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative way to solve this problem if you do not want your C Extension (or ctypes DLL) to be tied to Python, such as a case where you want to create a C library with bindings in multiple languages, you must allow your C Extension to run for long periods, and you can modify the C Extension:

Include the signal header in the C Extension.

```cpp
#include <signal.h>
```

Create a signal handler typedef in the C Extension.

```cpp
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
```

Add signal handlers in the C extension that will perform the actions necessary to interrupt any long running code (set a stop flag, etc.), and save the existing Python signal handlers.

```cpp
sighandler_t old_sig_int_handler = signal(SIGINT, your_sig_handler);
sighandler_t old_sig_term_handler = signal(SIGTERM, your_sig_handler);
```

Restore the existing signal handlers whenever the C extension returns. This step ensures that the Python signal handlers are re-applied.

```cpp
signal(SIGINT, old_sig_int_handler);
signal(SIGTERM, old_sig_term_handler);
```

If the long-running code is interrupted (flag, etc.), return control to Python with a return code indicating the signal number.

```cpp
return SIGINT;
```

In Python, send the signal received in the C extension.

```py
import os
import signal

status = c_extension.run()

if status in [signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM]:
    os.kill(os.getpid(), status)
```

Python will perform the action you are expecting, such as raising a KeyboardInterrupt for SIGINT.

Comment: Read [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant, but the only approach I found that also interrupts external library calls in C++ and kills any running child processes.

```cpp
#include <csignal>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

void catch_signals() {
  auto handler = [](int code) { throw std::runtime_error("SIGNAL " + std::to_string(code)); };
  signal(SIGINT, handler);
  signal(SIGTERM, handler);
  signal(SIGKILL, handler);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m)
{
    m.def("some_func", []()
    {
        catch_signals();
        // ...
    });
}
```

```py
import sys

from example import some_func

try:
    some_func()
except RuntimeError as e:
    if "SIGNAL" in str(e):
        code = int(str(e).rsplit(" ", 1)[1])
        sys.exit(128 + code)
    raise
```