# signal.alarm not triggering exception on time

Tags: python, timeout, signals

I've slightly modified the signal example from the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.alarm) (bottom of page).

I'm calling `sleep 10` but I would like an alarm to be raised after 1 second. When I run the following snippet it takes way more than 1 second to trigger the exception (I think it runs the full 10 seconds).

```
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Interrupted', signum
    raise IOError("Should after 1 second")

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(1)

os.system('sleep 10')

signal.alarm(0)
```

How can I be sure to terminate a function after a timeout in a single-threaded application?

Comment: Doesn't your call to the system `sleep` suspend everything, including the signal timer? The alarm doesn't go off because it's asleep too. You probably have to push that `sleep` call into a separate process with the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html):

> A Python signal handler does not get executed inside the low-level (C)
>   signal handler. Instead, the low-level signal handler sets a flag
>   which tells the virtual machine to execute the corresponding Python
>   signal handler at a later point(for example at the next bytecode
>   instruction).

Therefore, a signal such as that generated by `signal.alarm()` can't terminate a function after a timeout in some cases. Either [the function should cooperate by allowing other Python code to run (e.g., by calling `PyErr_CheckSignals()` periodically in C code)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16778026/4279) or you should [use a separate process, to terminate the function in time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26664130/4279).

Your case can be fixed if you use `subprocess.check_call('sleep 10'.split())` instead of `os.system('sleep 10')`.