# Keyboard Interrupt from Python does not abort Rust function (PyO3)

Tags: python, rust, keyboardinterrupt, pyo3

I have a Python library written in Rust with PyO3, and it involves some expensive calculations (up to 10 minutes for a single function call). How can I abort the execution when calling from Python ?

Ctrl+C seems to only be handled after the end of the execution, so is essentially useless.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
# Cargo.toml

[package]
name = "wait"
version = "0.0.0"
authors = []
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "wait"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies.pyo3]
version = "0.10.1"
features = ["extension-module"]
```

```rust
// src/lib.rs

use pyo3::wrap_pyfunction;

#[pyfunction]
pub fn sleep() {
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(10000));
}

#[pymodule]
fn wait(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_wrapped(wrap_pyfunction!(sleep))
}
```

```sh
$ rustup override set nightly
$ cargo build --release
$ cp target/release/libwait.so wait.so
$ python3
>>> import wait
>>> wait.sleep()
```

Immediately after having entered `wait.sleep()` I type `Ctrl + C`, and the characters `^C` are printed to the screen, but only 10 seconds later do I finally get

```
>>> wait.sleep()
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

The `KeyboardInterrupt` was detected, but was left unhandled until the end of the call to the Rust function. Is there a way to bypass that ?

The behavior is the same when the Python code is put in a file and executed from outside the REPL.

Comment: Aborting a thread in a compiled language such as Rust is not a safe operation: it would leave the process in an undetermined state.

Comment: My rust threads are read-only. Is there a way to bypass that restriction ?

Comment: What does "read-only thread" even mean? Threads are not safely cancellable, period. Now, `async` futures are designed to be cancellable at specific points (ie. `await`), but I don't know if PyO3 supports them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to spawn a separate process to run the Rust function. In the child process, we can set up a signal handler to exit the process on interrupt. Python will then be able to raise a KeyboardInterrupt exception as desired. Here's an example of how to do it:

```
// src/lib.rs
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::wrap_pyfunction;
use ctrlc;

#[pyfunction]
pub fn sleep() {
    ctrlc::set_handler(|| std::process::exit(2)).unwrap();
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(10000));
}

#[pymodule]
fn wait(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_wrapped(wrap_pyfunction!(sleep))
}
```

```
# wait.py
import wait
import multiprocessing as mp

def f():
    wait.sleep()

p = mp.Process(target=f)
p.start()
p.join()
print("Done")
```

Here's the output I get on my machine after pressing CTRL-C:

```
$ python3 wait.py
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "wait.py", line 9, in <module>
    p.join()
  File "/home/kerby/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 140, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/home/kerby/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 48, in wait
    return self.poll(os.WNOHANG if timeout == 0.0 else 0)
  File "/home/kerby/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 28, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Can confirm it works, the fact that it requires additional Python code is a bit of a dealbreaker: I am writing a library for other people, not an internal script. However I reckon that this requirement is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Might it be possible to treat the Python module generated by PyO3 as internal, wrapping it up in another Python module which would be the one exposed by the library and contain the subprocess-creating code? Then the end-user wouldn't have to deal with that.

Comment: That might be a solution. I'll look into the possibility of bundling together a `.so` library with a Python script that imports it into a single module. That would save end users from having to deal with multiple files. My PyO3 library is already a wrapper around another crate, so it would make quite a number of layers, although that's not much of a concern.

Comment: I just randomly found out that the additional Python code isn't even needed. I added 1 dependency to my `Cargo.toml`, one line for the `use ctrlc;` and one call to `ctrlc::set_handler` in my Rust library right before the call to the expensive function. Problem solved. The whole Python boilerplate code is not required.

Comment: The only thing to take note of is that if working from the REPL, then pressing `Ctrl+C` will not just abort the function but the whole session. That's fine for my own use case, but anyone finding this answer in the future should be warned.

Comment: Yes, if you remove the additional Python code, then the Rust function won't be running in a subprocess, hence `ctrlc` will cause the main process to exit. The purpose of the extra Python code was to make it so that recovery would be possible (i.e., but putting a try-except around the call to `.join()` to catch the KeyboardInterrupt), by ensuring that `ctrlc` only exits the child process. But if that's not required, then sure, it's a lot simpler without it.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930722/how-do-i-catch-an-interrupt-signal-in-python-when-inside-a-blocking-boost-c-me/39938987#39938987), except that your code is written in Rust instead of C++.

You did not say which platform you are using - I am going to assume it is unix-like. Some aspects of this answer may not be correct for Windows.

In unix-like systems, Ctrl+C results in a `SIGINT` signal being sent to your process. At the very low level of the C Library, applications can register functions which will be called when these signals are received. See [man signal(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for a more detailed description of signals.

Because signal handlers can be called at any time (even part way through some operation that you would normally consider atomic) there are big limits on what a signal handler can actually do. This is independent of the programming language or environment. Most programs just set a flag when they receive a signal and then return, and then later check that flag and take action on it.

Python is no different - it sets a signal handler for the `SIGINT` signal which sets some flag, which it that checks (when it is safe to do so) and takes action on.

This works OK when executing python code - it will check the flag at least once per code statement - but it is a different matter when executing a long running function written in Rust (or any other foreign language). The flag does not get checked until your rust function returns.

You can improve matters by checking the flag within your rust function. PyO3 [exposes](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.10.1/pyo3/ffi/fn.PyErr_CheckSignals.html) the [PyErr_CheckSignals](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_CheckSignals) function which does exactly that. This function:

> checks whether a signal has been sent to the processes and if so,
>   invokes the corresponding signal handler. If the signal module is
>   supported, this can invoke a signal handler written in Python. In all
>   cases, the default effect for SIGINT is to raise the KeyboardInterrupt
>   exception. If an exception is raised the error indicator is set and
>   the function returns -1; otherwise the function returns 0

So, you could call this function at suitable intervals inside your Rust function, and check the returned value. If it was -1, you should immediately return from your Rust function; otherwise keep going.

The picture is more complex if your Rust code is multi-threaded. You can only call `PyErr_CheckSignals` from the same thread as the python interpreter called you; and if it returns -1 you would have to clean up any other threads that you had started before returning. Exactly how to do that is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: My code just happens to be heavily multithreaded, but I'll work that out.

Comment: Sorry for un-accepting your answer, another answer gave me a way easier solution.

Comment: https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/marker/struct.Python.html#method.check_signals There is a safe Rust wrapper of PyErr_CheckSignals