# Forward `SIGINT` to Rust code when using Pyo3 without having handle this in all Rust code

Tags: rust, signals, pyo3

I am building a Python package which is mostly implemented in Rust, with bindings provided by [Pyo3](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3).

Some of the Rust calls can take a long time, and I would like to be able to interrupt the process with Ctrl-c while these calls are happening.
The previous question [Keyboard Interrupt from Python does not abort Rust function (PyO3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364030/keyboard-interrupt-from-python-does-not-abort-rust-function-pyo3) gives two possible solutions.
One requires that hooks are added throughout the code for the expensive operations to handle the interrupt.
This I would very much like to avoid.
The other uses the [ctrl](https://crates.io/crates/ctrlc) crate to set up a keyboard interrupt handler which exits the program.
The issue with this approach is that while it does stop the program, it also freezes the terminal with the following error

```
Keyboard interrupt received, exiting...
C:\arrow\cpp\src\arrow\filesystem\s3fs.cc:2598:  arrow::fs::FinalizeS3 was not called even though S3 was initialized.  This could lead to a segmentation fault at exit
```

This also happens when interrupting while pure Python code is running.

I guess what I ideally want is for the Rust code to handle the interrupt as it usually does and then for Python to throw a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception as usual.
Is there maybe some way to get the Rust code to act as though it has gotten a `SIGINT` signal? Is there some other way to exit while running Rust code without freezing the terminal?

---

The function which sets up the keyboard interrupt looks like this

```
#[pyfunction]
fn setup_keyboard_interrupt() {
    ctrlc::set_handler(move || {
        println!("Keyboard interrupt received, exiting...");
        std::process::exit(2);
    })
    .expect("Error setting Ctrl-C handler");
}
```

And I call it in `__init__.py`

I have tested this in Windows Powershell and WSL and get roughly the same results.

---

Is there some way to allow users to interrupt the program with Ctrl-c without having to think about it in all Rust code and without it freezing the terminal?

Comment: Maybe use [`crossbeam-channel`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/latest/crossbeam_channel/) to allow communication between Python and Rust, enabling Python to send a signal/Interrupt to the Rust program?

Comment: The problem is not detecting in Rust code that an interrupt has occurred. This is solved with the hook set with the `ctrlc` crate. The issue is what to do once an interrupt has been detected.