# How to make Ctrl+C work in C++ via pybind?

Tags: c++, exception, keyboardinterrupt

I have several C++ files
test1.cpp, ..., test10.cpp ,
test1.h, ... , test10.h

and test.py which calls functions in C++ files via pybind.

I try to handle exceptions.
When running test.py, if KeyboardInturrupt is occured, I hope running functions of C++ stop, but not works.

Even, I add PyErr_CheckSignals() in pybind same as  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33652496/13802668, but not worked.

How can I fix?

Comment: What do you mean by "_not worked._"? Please elaborate.

Comment: Did you tried registering signal handler in c++