# How to allow Jupyter to interrupt terminal running ctypes shared library

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have written a fairly small C++ shared library with a Python 3.10 interface. The underlying C++ program can take some time to run (anywhere from 1-5 minutes). If I run in terminal, a simple `^C` is enough to stop both the Python process and terminate the C++ library called. However, if I am running in a Jupyter Notebook, clicking 'interrupt the kernel' does not stop either process, and I must either wait for the process to finish (long) or terminate the entire Jupyter process.

Is there anything I can add to the library or Python API to allow jupyter to kill the C++ process?

I'm not sure that I completely understand how to solve the problem using these responses here: [CTRL+C doesn't interrupt call to shared-library using CTYPES in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271697/ctrlc-doesnt-interrupt-call-to-shared-library-using-ctypes-in-python)

Comment: So you're saying that you managed to call a function from a *C* *.dll* in *Python*, but you don't know for example to place that function call into a (*Python*) function to be run by a thread (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects)?

Comment: I suppose so. Is it just a matter of wrapping the function call like:
```
t = Thread(target=print, args=[1])
t.run()
```